# huge delay in fething records from controller to Lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a simple component which will fetch 90 records from the Controller. However it is taking at least 3 to 4 seconds. is there a way I can improve this performance?

controller:

```
({
     doInit : function(component, event, helper) {       
            var action = component.get("c.findByNameEngage");            
            action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
                component.set("v.engagements", a.getReturnValue());         
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action); 

    }
})
```

Apex:

```
public class tEngsccls {
     @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Engagement__c> findByNameEngage() {   
        List<Engagement__c> EngagementList =new List<Engagement__c>();

            EngagementList=[SELECT  Id,
                                    Learning_Community__c,
                                    Track_Assignment__c,
                                    Prospect_Track_Interest__c,
                                    Secondary_Specialty_Assignment__c, 
                                    Name 
                            FROM    Engagement__c 
                            LIMIT   90 ];

        return EngagementList;
    }
}
```

DEBUG LOGS:

```
10:02:23.0 (3814051)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|DEBUG|Before the Engagement Query
10:02:23.0 (3829503)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[6]
10:02:23.0 (3833301)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[6]|Bytes:150
10:02:23.0 (3846520)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[6]|Bytes:4
10:02:23.0 (9539843)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[6]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, Learning_Community__c, Track_Assignment__c, Prospect_Track_Interest__c, Secondary_Specialty_Assignment__c, Name FROM Engagement__c LIMIT 90
10:02:23.0 (19836987)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[6]|Rows:90
10:02:23.0 (19879839)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[6]|Bytes:364
10:02:23.0 (20004415)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[6]|Bytes:9447
10:02:23.0 (20068603)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[6]|Bytes:364
10:02:23.0 (20115005)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[6]|EngagementList|"List of size 90 too large to display"|0x3802ffda
10:02:23.0 (20126148)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[14]
10:02:23.0 (20139429)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[14]|Bytes:26
10:02:23.0 (20213935)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|After the Engagement Query
```

Performance:

[image]

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="tEngsccls" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="engagements" type="Engagement__c[]"/>

    <div class="slds-p-around--large">

        <div class="slds-card">                
            <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
                <div class="slds-media slds-media--center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                    <div class="slds-media__figure slds-icon slds-icon-standard-contact slds-icon--small">
                        <img src="/resource/LDS/assets/icons/standard/contact_60.png" alt="Placeholder" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-media__body">
                        <h2 class="slds-text-heading--small slds-truncate">Engagement  ({!v.engagements.length})</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>                        
            </div>
        </div> 
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.engagements.length>0}">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal" >            
                <thead>
                    <tr class="slds-text-heading--label"> 
                        <th > Engagement Name </th>
                        <th > Learning Community </th>
                        <th > Specialty Assignment </th>
                        <th > Secondary Specialty Assignment </th>
                        <th > Specialty Interest </th>
                    </tr>            
                </thead> 
                <tbody>   
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.engagements}" var="n">
                        <tr>
                            <td data-label="Name" title="Name">
                                <div>{!n.Name}</div>               
                            </td>
                            <td data-label="Learning Community" title="Learning Community"> 
                                <ui:inputSelect aura:id="lcapply" class="slds-input"
                                                labelClass="slds-form-element__label" value="{!n.Learning_Community__c}">            
                                    <ui:inputSelectOption text="Select Learning Community..."/>
                                </ui:inputSelect>
                            </td>
                            <td data-label="Specialty Assignment" title="Specialty Assignment">                            
                                <ui:inputSelect class="slds-input"
                                                labelClass="slds-form-element__label" aura:id="spapply" value="{!n.Track_Assignment__c}">            
                                    <ui:inputSelectOption text="Select Specialty Assignment..."/>                                  
                                </ui:inputSelect>
                            </td>
                            <td data-label="Secondary Specialty Assignment" title="Secondary Specialty Assignment">                            
                                <ui:inputSelect class="slds-input"
                                                labelClass="slds-form-element__label" value="{!n.Secondary_Specialty_Assignment__c}">            
                                    <ui:inputSelectOption text="Select Specialty Assignment..."/>
                                </ui:inputSelect>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div>{!n.Prospect_Track_Interest__c}</div>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <center>No Records found.</center>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Query Plan:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64959/discussion-on-question-by-ajay-huge-delay-in-fething-records-from-controller-to).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could refactor the component. All is good now. Thanks.

UPDATE:

I used lightning:select instead ui:select. Things are OK now.

Comment: Did u find out what the issue was?